# MouseHook for MouseEventHandler

Tags: c#, mouseevent, hook, mousewheel

I want to capture MouseWheel with this code. But I have a problem with this line:

```
MouseWheell(null,new MouseEventArgs());
```

It says:

> There is no argument given that correspods to required formal
>   parameter 'button' of `MouseEventArgs.MouseEventArgs(MouseButton,int,
>   int, int, int)`

How can I fix that ? Thanks

```
public static class MouseHook

{
    public static event EventHandler MouseAction = delegate { };
    public static event MouseEventHandler MouseWheell = delegate { };

    public static void Start()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }
    public static void stop()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
            if (hook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
            return hook;
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
      int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            MouseAction(null, new EventArgs());
        }
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages) wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            MouseWheell(null,new MouseEventArgs());
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
      LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
      IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);


}
```

Comment: Mousewheel is not always functional following the context (focus and mousewheel are linked).  its the reason i'd prefer to use SendInput to generate the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have adapted the answer to your code..

```
    public static class MouseHook
    {
        public static event EventHandler MouseAction = delegate { };
        public static event MouseEventHandler MouseWheell = delegate { };

        public const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
        public const uint MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;

public static void Start()
{
    _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
}
public static void stop()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
}

private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
{
    using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
    {
        IntPtr hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle("user32"), 0);
        if (hook == IntPtr.Zero) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        return hook;
    }
}

private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private static IntPtr HookCallback(
  int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
    {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
        MouseAction(null, new EventArgs());
    }
    if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages) wParam)
    {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT lparam = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
        int wheelvalue = (Int16)(lparam.mouseData >> 16) < 0 ? -120 : 120; // Forward = 120, Backward = -120
        //MouseWheell(null,new MouseEventArgs());

            var input = new INPUT[1];
            input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input[0].mi = MouseInput(0, 0, (uint)wheelvalue, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL);
            SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input[0].GetType()));
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

private MOUSEINPUT MouseInput(int x, int y, uint data, uint t, uint flag)
{
    return new MOUSEINPUT { dx = x, dy = y, mouseData = data, time = t, dwFlags = flag };
}

private enum MouseMessages
{
    WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
    WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
    WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
    WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
    WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
    WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct POINT
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
{
    public POINT pt;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint flags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int type;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT hi;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int dx;
    public int dy;
    public uint mouseData;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public uint time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint uMsg;
        public ushort wParamL;
        public ushort wParamH;
    }

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern uint SendInput(uint num_inputs, INPUT[] inputs, int size);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
  LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
  IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Comment: It is too complicated for me. Can you just edit my code to fix my problem ?

Comment: Thanks but there is a problem with these lines:




 input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
            input[0].mi = MouseInput(0, 0, (uint)wheelvalue, 0, MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL);


IT says: The name ' INPUT_MOUSE' does not exist current context and 'MouseInput'

Comment: hum sorry i have just forgotten the function MouseInput...
        its fixed

Comment: and i have added the const INPUT_MOUSE , (value 0)